# Refresh AJAX function (gets PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Let me first say that I've been coding for less than a week. I'm trying to create a javascript that will refresh my data using an AJAX call that will spit out a PHP's JSON encoded file into a more readable file.

I've successfully spit out the json into an HTML table, however, I want to auto refresh this data so when the database changes, so will my HTML.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

refresh();
});

function refresh() {
setTimeout( function() {
dbupdates(); 
refresh();
}, 500);
}   

function dbupdates(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetchtest.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
// for loop to only write 10 
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            var id01 = response[i].id1; 
            var id02 = response[i].id2;
            var id03 = response[i].id3;
// tr located in html
            var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + id01 + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + id02 + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + id03 + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
// table ID in html file
            $("#HTMLTABLE").append(tr_str);  
        }

    }
});
};
```

When I run the web page, it goes into an infinite loop where it just creates new 10 entries table of the same data (probably does change if db changes).

I know exactly why this happens but what function do I need to use to actually refresh only 10 table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No use append() replace into html() function use solved your problems

```
  <div id="HTMLTABLE"></div>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        refresh();
        });

        function refresh() {
        setTimeout( function() {
        dbupdates(); 
        refresh();
        }, 1500);
        }   

        function dbupdates(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetchtest.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
        // for loop to only write 10 
         var tr_str ='';
                for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                    var id01 = response[i].id; 
                    var id02 = response[i].name;
                    var id03 = response[i].salery;
        // tr located in html
                     tr_str += "<tr>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + id01 + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + id02 + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + id03 + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
        // table ID in html file

                }
             $("#HTMLTABLE").html(tr_str);

            }
        });
        };
 </script>
```

Comment: This seems to have stopped the infinite loop, but now it only fetch the first array and not 10. Do I have a problem in my loop statement? Thanks

Comment: Still didn't work, only spit out one of each id01, 02,03. This is my json file [{"id1":"34","id2":"0625SS036 ","id3":"40"},{"id1":"105","id2":"0625SS107 ","id3":"40"},{"jid1":"118","id2":"0625SS120 ","id3":"35"}, ....... (200+ string)

Comment: I will try out childRemove or some append remove below or on top of my return script.

Comment: I have run code on my system is work is fine but your system i don't know now edit this code and try. Php json data is worked fine.

Comment: I got it to work by adding empty syntax as follows.. (still used append instead of html because it somehow is the only thing that follows my less than 10 loop)                                                                                                 function dbupdates(){
 $("#HTMLTABLE").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetchtest.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){

Comment: Thanks for your help Khetesh

Comment: Welcome @counterlogic